# java programming factorial help please

Tags: java, joptionpane, factorial

I'm taking a virtual high school class that is not what i thought it would be, and I am very confused to say the least.  My homework is this:

Exercise 6.1
In mathematics, the a factorial of a number is denoted by writing n! and is the product of n and all the other numbers less than n. For instance, 5! Is 5*4*3*2*1.

- Create a new project named Factorial.
- Write a factorial method that takes an integer as a parameter and returns the result as an
  integer. It should use a loop to calculate the factorial.
- In main, prompt the user for a number, then call the factorial method. Display the result that was returned.

This is the code  I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

class Factorial
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a number.");
        int numberChoice = Integer.parseInt(choice);
        int triple;
        triple = factorialNumber(numberChoice);
        System.out.println(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, triple, "Output:"));
    }

    // int num;
    //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //num = input.nextInt();
    //int FactInput = factorialNumber(num);

    public static double factorialNumber(int){
        //declaring variables
        //int num;
        int fact=1; //placeholder
        //using the scanner
        // Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //user input
        System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
        // num = input.nextInt();
        //for statement
        for (int i=2;i<=num; i++){
            //multiple assignment
            fact=fact*i;
            //print the result
            System.out.print("The factorial of your number is ");
            return fact;

        }
        return fact;
    }
}
```

Where do I go from here??
All help is appreciated- thank you!!

Comment: What's the problem exactly?

Comment: Ditch all references to `swing` or `JOptionPane`. They are confusing you and are unnecessary, as this problem can be solved with command line only.

Comment: It looks like the main problem in your code is that you `return` within the loop where you calculate the factorial.  Also, you generally don't want to use floating point math unless you need to (`public static double factorialNumber(int)` should be `public static int factorialNumber(int)`).

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you have it down for the most part.  You don't need to return within your for loop.  You can only return the factorial after the for loop is done, because that is when the calculation is finished.  Also, don't worry about printing your output in the factorialNumber() method.  Your method finds the value and then you can print it out within your main method.

1.Get the number for factorial
2.Send it to the factorialNumber() method
3.Run the for loop until your index reaches the number
4.Return the value.
5.Print the value

Some other errors:
-System.out.println(JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, triple, "Output:"));  -> omit the System.out.println
-public static double factorialNumber(int){   should have " num" after "int"
-remove the SYstem.out.println and return within your for loop

Answer (score 1):

It's better to use long rather than int, the factorial grows fast.
Here is a simple function that uses [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion)

```
private static long factorial(int n) {
    return (n==1)?1:n*factorial(n-1);
}

System.out.println(factorial(20)); // gives 2432902008176640000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println("Output: " + triple);

static int factorialNumber(int num) {
```

No System.out.println in the factorial function at the end.

Remove the return inside the loop; you would loop once, and return.

And try using the single step option in the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Factorial of any number always grow rapidly. So you need to make sure that you take proper data type. Your program only takes int and in Java, the integer is 32 bits and range from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647. So if your factorial computation goes beyond that int limit then your program may not give the expected result. Refer to this link [factorial using big integer](http://www.javawithus.com/programs/factorial-using-big-integer)